# Handling Dynamic Database Connections

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, spring-jdbc

My applications requirement is to create database connections on the fly. Database connection details are not known at compile time and are provided to the application at run time only. Only one connection is required to process one request and the scope of the connection is up to the request execution cycle only. Same user may or may not post a new request with the database connection details. We can have hundreds of such users, hence if suppose all of them post request at the same time, my application will have to create hundreds of such database connections.

Based on this scenario, I have got below questions/need clarifications-

1. Connection pooling will not work here as database connections are
       dynamic?
2. What is the best way to create database connections in this scenario? A pure JDBC connection will be best here?
3. Creating hibernate session factory for every request, just to create a single connection will cause overhead? Or can we do that?
4. What are others possible good ways to handle such a scenario?

Edit: 
My application is a component of a bigger web application. This bigger Web application has its own storage on the cloud. Any user can create a sandbox on this storage. Hence, while placing a request for the data load user has to pass on the credentials.

I am new to hibernate and spring. Please help me in deciding the best possible architecture for this.

Comment: Where are you configuring the datasource details ? properties file ? xml file ? Do they come from a separate service at runtime ?

Comment: Database details like host name, Port no, etc are stored in a backend database. However, user schema details like username, password are passed along with request by the user.

Comment: so you are creating one schema per user ?

Comment: Why do you think you need Hibernate if the database connections will be known only at runtime? To run user supplied SQL queries? Or you somehow know the entities beforehand, even if you don't know where the database will be? I don't understand.

Comment: @JohnDonn- entity structures are known at compile time.

Comment: @javaguy- a single user can create multiple schemas. Schema name, username, password along the database key is passed in the request object.

Comment: @sf9251 So what's the big picture? You want to create a multitenancy application, but with connection details in every request? If you're new to Hibernate and Spring, how do you expect to get even a somewhat decent architecture, let alone "the best possible"?

Comment: If entites are known at compile time, then you need to create manually the Hibernate session factories, and yes, this will cause an overhead - but only for the first request where the db connection is specified - you should be able to cache the session factories for subsequent requests specifying the same db connection.

Comment: It's not that this would be impossible. However I'd like to know what the idea is behind this, because it might after all be a really horrible idea. A lot of people here (who often helpfully inform that they're *new* to something) spend time worrying about whether they can instead of whether they should.

Comment: @Kayaman- I have explained the details of my application above. Could you pls let me know what part you didn't understood? If it can be restructured in a better way, please let me know.

Comment: Your design choices are horrible. I think you better explain us why you are forced to have the users pass their login and password to database in the request, because that sounds like crazy (and probably comes from a misunderstanding about how the frameworks work). Yet if you are resolved to do it, this is possible. For example you could try using the scope `request` on your bean `sessionFactory`

Comment: @Aldian my application is a component of a bigger web application. This bigger Web application has its own storage on the cloud. Any user can create a sandbox on this storage. Hence, while placing a request for the data load user has to pass on the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might find the [Open Session in View](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView) Pattern interesting for your use case. You would just have to suppress the `private SessionFactory sf;` field and build a new one at each call.

Or if you have a big heap and a big probability that a same user will call several times, you could implement some sort of static HashMap associating a given user with a given SessionFactory and reuse it if already existing.

No then about your questions:

1. Connexion Pooling will not be possible unless you implement it yourself. But before thinking about it, ask yourself is there is a probability for a same user needing several connections at once.
2. I think that the solution I suggested is among the least worst, provided you need hibernate support for managing your entities
3. It will cause overhead and there is no way around it beside hacking deep in the framework with probable undesirable side effects. For instance you could imagine using a `ThreadLocal` to assign a SessionFactory to each thread (from the pool managed by tomcat), then on each call, set the datasource corresponding to the user, see code below
4. You will have to give a lot more details about your application and its internal before I can (maybe) advise you on this point.

Here is the code I spoke about in 3. **Keep in mind this is bad design**. Also I took some shortcuts to make the trick quickly understandable. No Idea if it would actually work, but you can give it a try

```
public class HibernateSessionRequestFilter implements Filter {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HibernateSessionRequestFilter.class);
    private static ThreadLocal<LocalSessionFactoryBean> lsfbth = new ThreadLocal<LocalSessionFactoryBean>();
    private static final Map<Object, DataSource> datasourceMap = new HashMap<>();

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        log.debug("Initializing filter...");
        LocalSessionFactoryBean lsfb = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        lsfb.setHibernateProperties(null); // TODO: add correct values
        lsfbth.set(lsfb);
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
            ServletException {

        LocalSessionFactoryBean lsfb = lsfbth.get();
        String credentials = null; //TODO: get user login from request
        DataSource dataSource = datasourceMap.get(credentials);
        if( dataSource==null){
            // TODO: build datasource here
            datasourceMap.put(credentials, dataSource);
        }
        lsfb.setDataSource(dataSource);
        SessionFactory sf = lsfb.getObject();
```